# Convert local time to UTC in .NET framework 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I develop an app. in c#, I should translate local time  to UTC, the local time is in time zone that who that use in my app. enters. I must use in .NET framework 3.0, so can't use the TimeZoneInfo object.

Does anyone  has an idia how can I do it?

Should use in TimeZone Object?

Thanks

Maybe I can't do it?

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548235/convert-utc-datetime-to-another-time-zone or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439468/utc-to-users-local-time - and reverse the algorithm

Comment: I can't use in TimeZoneInfo object, because it is no in framework 3.0

Answer (score 6):

Now I see the problem. Use the following method instead:
[TimeZone.ToUniversalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.touniversaltime%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I know, but how can I know in my app what the UTC offset of the TimeZone that the user enter? and how can I takes into account the daylight saving time rule?

Comment: This is done for you automatically (assuming your app is local, not web). Check examples on MSDN.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, which is object in c# done it automatically? where is the example in MSDN?

Comment: DateTime.ToUniversalTime is the link pointing to MSDN article. There are usage examples at the bottom of the page.

Comment: it is good to convert local time in the time zone that the computer is located to UTC, but in my app I get from the user Time zone - that it is no my time zone, and date in this time zone, and I should translate from this time zone to UTC. the DateTime.ToUniversalTime help only to convert dateTime in computer time zone to UTC.

Comment: Check update. Details depends on how you get the time zone offset from user.

Comment: sould I ask from the user the offset? or I have a option to calculate by myself in my app. as the TimeZoneInfo?

Comment: I can't say anything until I know what's the application type and how it interacts with the user and user's operating system.

Answer (score 0):

every time I save time in a database I **ALWAYS save in UTC time**

```
myEntity.CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

**Now, in 3.0 or less**

use this file

> http://pastebin.com/w20NRkuP

it **contains a helper** so you can list all **Timezones** and have their values. Add it to your db or use on-the-fly.

Fill up a **dropdown and ask user to choose it's own TimeZone**, then, just add the Minutes to your saved UTC Date.

for example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDropDown" runat="server" />
```

then

```
myDropDown.DataSource = Helper.ListAllTimeZones();
myDropDown.DataValueField = "UtcOffsetMinutes";
myDropDown.DataTextField = "DisplayName";

myDropDown.DataBind();
```

when saving user preferences:

```
User.OffSet = (int)myDropDown.SelectedValue;
```

hope it helps

---

for example, [sweetie.com](http://sueetie.com/) does this:

[image]

just request the timezone to the user and save all in UTC time, then just add/subtract the timezone.

Comment: but I don't have a TimeZoneInfo object in FrameWork 3.0

Comment: dumb me :( to get a list of TimeZones in 3.0: http://staceyw1.wordpress.com/2006/08/31/convert-local-time-to-timezone/ big and stupip, but it's the only way, or get it once and create your own object with this info.

Comment: added a class so it would be easier to use.